# How do I implement Unit Of Work in Spring & JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, domain-driven-design

I am trying to get my head around the concept of UOW and how I can implement it in my spring/jpa/hibernate app with DDD. I make my methods transactional, but how do I make sure that all the entities that have been changed in the transaction get persisted? Is it by using cascading collections or is there another way?

Comment: You might also want to study the sample DDD application - http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/42

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hibernate implements Unit of Work internally. That is, all changes made to *persistent* entities inside a transaction are persisted automatically (unless you have a transaction with `readOnly = true`).

Cascading options are needed to configure transition of graphs of *transient* or *detached* entities to *persistent* state.

**See also:**

- [11.1. Hibernate object states](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview)

Comment: Ok, so if I have a application service method "@transactional updateUser(User user)" then there is no need to call repository.store(user) after changing the user?

Comment: @Piotr: If `User` comes from the outside of transaction, perhaps it's _detached_, so you need to `merge()` it to persistence context in order to make it _persistent_.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I make sure that all the entities that have been changed in the transaction get persisted?

That's default behaviour for the JPA EntityManager.

Read [this section of the Java EE 5 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbrc) (all the way down to **Synchronizing Entity Data to the Database**)